# How do I choose the current sourcing pin in CTMU? (pic microcontroller)

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I want to configure CTMU to apply current on pin 17 (AN10), and then measure the voltage. I looked at the CTMUCON and CTMUICON registers in PIC24F16KA101([datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39927c.pdf)). There are no bits to determine which analog pin would source the current. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The CTMU function provides the current source internally to whichever analog channel is initialized.  You must initialize the ADC and analog channel before initializing the CTMU and enabling the current source, then perform the ADC conversion.  Look at the current calibration routines in https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Charge%20Time%20Measurement%20Unit%20CTMU%20DS-39724b.pdf for some example code.